# AndroidX Android Studio 3.5.2 set actionbar title Null

Tags: android

I am trying to set the title for the activity with the Navigation Drawer layout. However, I am getting the error below. In fact, the previous version of android working fine with the similar code.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
>               at com.aua.archi.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)

I am not sure what is wrong here and is there anything change with Android Studio 3.5.2 with `AndroidX` and Material Design components.

## JAVA

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    private MaterialToolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    }
}
```

## XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/news_drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/fragment_container"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar_layout" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/nva_drawer_item_text_color"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/nva_drawer_item_text_color"
        app:itemBackground="@drawable/nav_item_bg"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_drawer" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

## Toolbar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary"
    tools:targetApi="lollipop" />
```

Comment: That stack trace doesn't match up with your code. `getSupportActionBar()` will not return an `android.app.ActionBar`, and I don't see where you're calling `setTitle()` anywhere.

Comment: Anyway, I'll just assume that those are old logs from a different test run, and that you are currently running the given code and XML. Your issue would then be the ID you've set on the `<include>` element. It overrides the ID on the root `View` in the included layout, so your `MaterialToolbar` ends up with ID `toolbar_layout`, and `findViewById(R.id.toolbar)` will return null. Either remove the ID from the `<include>`, or change the `findViewById()` call to pass `R.id.toolbar_layout` instead.

Comment: check below answer

Comment: @MikeM. Ah! actually I missed the `SetTitle` like to post here but I have already tried after `actionBar = getSupportActionBar();` like `actionBar.setTitle()`

Comment: @MikeM. I just read second comment. Let me try that and back to you. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @MikeM. after setting `toolbar_layout` for `toolbar` solves the problem. I thought I need to set actual toolbar id rather included layout. Thanks a lot. I don't know how to make this question as solved or delete it or leave it like this?

Comment: I've already closed it as a duplicate, since it's a rather common issue, so it's basically marked as resolved, as is. It's completely up to you, as to whether you want to keep it or delete it. Anyhoo, glad you got it working. Cheers!

Comment: Alright! once again thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    />
```

and in activity

```
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
```

```
private Toolbar toolbar;
```

and set text to toolbar

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
toolbar.setText("asdfsdf");
```